# Workflow 2013: Creation and modification problem

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server

Recently, I got an error when I modified my workflow in SharePoint 2013.
It shows me this error: 
[image: error message]
After restarting , it gives me the same message.

It gives me another error message when i refresh:
[image: error message 2]

I can modify and save workflow 2010 but i can't publish them.
It gives me this error:

> Errors were found whend compoling the workflow. The workflow files
>   were saved but cannot be run. Could not publish the workflow because
>   the workflow configuration file contains errors.

I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workflow Manager Client 1.0** was the problem.

During the SharePoint Designer installation, "Workflow Manager Client 1.0" is install too.

If you running SharePoint Designer on your personal computer and not on the server, uninstall it, this will fix the problem.